# Generating function of total sales on a given day

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given the problem below:

The number of customers that shop at Elmo’s World of Food on a given day is geometrically distributed with parameter $p_1$. The number of items a customer buys at Elmo’s is geometrically distributed with parameter $p_2$. The distribution of the cost of each item is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Assume that the amount customers buy and the amount of prices of items are independent. Let $X$ denote the total sales on a given day. Find the generating function of $X$.

In my **attempt** on solving this I let $N_c$ denote the number of customers that shop on a given fay, $N_i$ denote the number of items a customer buys, and $C$ cost of each item. Then we can write $X = \sum_{k=1}^{N_c} N_i\cdot C$. To find the generating function I used the MGF: $E[e^{tX}]$ and to compute it I conditioned on $N_c$ first and then on $C$. However, my work became very tedious and I'm stuck at simplifying the expression I got. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a different approach I could use in finding the generating function of $X$? This is just a practice problem as I study for my exam.

Comment: Must the function be a moment generating function, or will an ordinary generating function do?  By an ordinary GF I mean something like $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n x^n$$

Comment: @awkward The question is to find the generating function. The MGF is the one I am familiar with and that's why I worked with it. How would you go about finding the ordinary generating function?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think the method I was originally thinking about will work when the cost is a continuous random variable.  So maybe a moment generating function will work-- I'll have to think about the problem some more.

Comment: @awkward No problem. I appreciate your time anyways!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** The moment generating function for the total sales/profits is
$$ M_X(t) = \textbf{E}[e^{t X}] = \frac{\lambda p_1 p_2}{\lambda p_1 p_2 - t} \qquad \text{where} \qquad(\lambda p_1 p_2 > t).$$

**Solution:**
To clarify the question a bit: $X$ is the total profit (i.e., total costs of all products purchased) on a given day and since $X$ is effectively a continuous random variable and ["generating functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) are typically defined as a way to encode the coefficients of an infinite sequence, I'll assume you want to calculate the *moment* generating function for $X$.

In order to compute the moment generating function for $X$, we need to compute the probability density function (PDF) for $X$.

By the prompt, we know that the probability that $k$ customers enter the store is $(1-p_1)^{k-1}p_1$. The probability that a single one of those customers purchases $\ell$ items is $(1-p_2)^{\ell-1} p_2$. And the probability density for the cost of a single item is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$.

In order to find the PDF for $X$, we need to compute the probabilities for sums of random variables. In particular, the probability that $k$ people purchase a total of $m$ items and that the total cost of these $m$ items is $X$. We note two things

- The sum of $k$ geometric random variables with probability of success $p$ is a negative binomial random variable with parameters $k$ and $p$: $\binom{m-1}{k-1} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}$
- The sum of $m$ exponential random variables with rate $\beta$ is a gamma $(m, \beta)$ random variable: $\beta^m x^{m-1} e^{-\beta x}/(m-1)!$

Thus the probability that $m$ items are bought by $k$ customers is $\binom{m-1}{k-1} p_2^k (1-p_2)^{m-k}$, and the PDF for the total costs (i.e., profits) from $m$ items is $\lambda^m X^{m-1} e^{-\lambda X}/(m-1)!$.

The PDF for $k$ customers visiting the store and purchasing a total of $m$ items which have a total cost of $X$ is then
\begin{align}p(k, m, X) &= (1-p_1)^{k-1} p_1 \times\binom{m-1}{k-1} p_2^k (1-p_2)^{m-k}\times\frac{\lambda^m }{(m-1)!}X^{m-1} e^{-\lambda X}\\[.5em]
& = \lambda p_1 p_2 \frac{\left(\lambda p_2(1-p_1) X\right)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\frac{\left(\lambda (1-p_2) X\right)^{m-k}}{(m-k)!} e^{-\lambda X}.
\end{align}
To find the PDF for the cost alone, we sum over all possible values of $m$ and $k$. We have
\begin{align}
\rho_{\text{cost}}(X) & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=k}^{\infty}p(k, m, X)\\[.5em]
& = \lambda p_1 p_2 \exp\left( \lambda p_2(1-p_1)X\right) \exp\left( \lambda(1-p_2) X\right) \exp(-\lambda X)\\[.5em] 
& = \lambda p_1 p_2 \exp(-\lambda p_1 p_2 X).
\end{align}
The moment generating function is then
$$ M_X(t) = \textbf{E}[e^{t X}] = \lambda p_1 p_2 \int^{\infty}_{0} dX\, e^{tX - \lambda p_1 p_2 X} = \frac{\lambda p_1 p_2}{\lambda p_1 p_2 - t} \qquad (\lambda p_1 p_2 > t).$$

**Random Note:** The problem's stated conditions/assumptions seem odd. I would expect the number of people in a store and the number of items each person purchases to follow something more like a poisson distribution and binomial distribution, respectively, rather than geometric distributions. Geometric distributions characterize discrete survival processes which doesn't seem to well model whether people enter a store or how many items they buy.

Comment: Can you explain $(1-p_1)^{k-1} p_1 $ in the third equation from the bottom?

Comment: @AntoniParellada It comes from the definition of the geometric distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: Yes, I see that, but you had already summed both geometric pmf's into a negative binomial at that step...

Comment: No. I only summed the distribution corresponding to the number of items purchased by $k$ customers (i.e., the geometric distribution defined by $p_2$). The geometric corresponding to the number of customers in the store is not summed.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

We need to distinguish between two different kinds of probability generating functions: the ordinary power series generating function (OPSGF) and the moment-generating function (MGF).  Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable that takes on only values in $0,1,2,3,\dots$; then we define the OPSGF of $X$ as
$$f(z) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} p(x) z^n$$
where $p(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$.  Equivalently, we may write $f(z) = E[z^x]$.  The MGF of $X$ is defined by $g(t) = E[e^{tx}]$.  The MGF has the advantage that it can be applied to continuous random variables as well as discrete.  There is a simple relation between the two types of generating functions: if $f(z)$ is the OPSGF and $g(z)$ is the MGF, then $g(t) = f(e^t)$.

A useful property of the OPSGF applies to sums of a random number of random variables.  If $X_1, X_2, X_3,...$ are independent random variables all having the OPSGF $f(z)$ and $N$ is an integer random variable with OPSGF $g(z)$, then the OPSGF of $Y= \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is $g(f(z))$.  If $f(z)$ is a MGF, then $g(f(z))$ is the MGF of $Y$.

Applying this property to our question, we see that if $f(z)$ is the OPSGF of a geometric random variable with parameter $p_1$, $g(z)$ is the OPSGF of a geometric random variable with parameter $p_2$, and $h(t)$ is the MGF of an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$, then the MGF of the total sales is $f(g(h(t)))$.  If you carry out the computation, I think you will find that the total sales have an exponential distribution.

Hint: The OPSGF of a geometric random variable with pdf $(1-p)^{k-1}p$ is
$$f(z) = \frac{pz}{1-(1-p)z}$$

If you are interested in more information about the uses of the OPSGF in probability, one source is *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Volume I, Third Edition* by William Feller.